# Llamaindex OpenAIEmbedding AttributeError: OpenAIEmbedding has no attribute 'embed_documents'

Tags: python, openai-api, large-language-model, llama-index

```
print('loading dependencies')
from pathlib import Path
from llama_index import download_loader
from llama_index import VectorStoreIndex, ServiceContext, SimpleDirectoryReader
from llama_index import set_global_service_context
from llama_index.embeddings import OpenAIEmbedding
from llama_index import LangchainEmbedding
from llama_index.llms import AzureOpenAI
PandasExcelReader = download_loader("PandasExcelReader")
import openai
import os

print('initalizing openapi key')
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "my_key"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"] = "my_base"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_TYPE"] = "azure"
os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"] = "2023-05-15"
deployment_name='gpt-35-turbo'

openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_base = "my_base"
openai.api_version = "2023-05-15"
openai.api_key = "my_key"


#embed model
print('creating embeddings model')
llm = AzureOpenAI(engine="davinci-gpt3", model="text-davinci-003", temperature=0.0)

#load document from path
print('loading document')

loader = PandasExcelReader(pandas_config={"header":0})
documents = loader.load_data(file=Path("\my\path.xlsx"), sheet_name=None) #excel with multiple sheets

#creating embedding_llm
print('creating embedding_llm')
embedding_llm = LangchainEmbedding(
    OpenAIEmbedding(
        model="text-embedding-ada-002",
        deployment="embeddings",
        openai_api_key="my_key",
        openai_api_base='my_base',
        openai_api_type='azure',
        openai_api_version='2023-05-15',
    ),
    embed_batch_size=1,
)

#create service context
print('creating service context')
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
    llm=llm,
    embed_model=embedding_llm,
)

#setting global service context
print('setting global service context')
set_global_service_context(service_context)

print('creating index')
#create index from documents
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
print('success')
```

Above is my code - I am using llamaindex to create an index on an excel workbook with multiple sheets and would like to save the embeddings. The ultimate goal is to use the index as a query engine for a chatbot

In this line:

```
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(documents)
```

I keep getting an attributeerror: 'object has no attribute embed_documents'. I've tried loading the file with SimpleDirectoryReader as well and get the same exact error. I'm not really sure where it's coming from since I never call that function anyways. Would anyone be able to shed light or point me in the right direction on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that we should use `langchain.embeddings` instead of `llama_index.embeddings`. So replace the following code:

```
from llama_index.embeddings import OpenAIEmbedding
```

with this:

```
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
```

and modify `OpenAIEmbedding` to `OpenAIEmbeddings`